# Flip and size expand button animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, flip

I want to flip and expand button using animation

Code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:mybutton cache:YES];
[mybutton setFrame:CGRectMake(mybutton.frame.origin.x, mybutton.frame.origin.x, 200, 200)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

There are problems in this animation:
- Button is flipping but it's expanding after half round flip is made.
- Button location isn't accurate after it's flipped.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the setFrame completely, it should flip better. Also try setting cache to NO. According to the documentation you shouldn't modify the view that is transitioning during the animation itself - cache:NO will help, but it still isn't right.

You typically have a parent view that is given to the setAnimationTransition function, then right after you take the old child and remove it from the subview, then add the new child. This gives the illusion of one child subview being flipped behind and the new child being flipped into focus. The transition happens on the parent though that contains the child.

Either way, try commenting out the setFrame for a minute and it should look more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Since they both are separate animations, you can also try to use an AnimationDidStopSelector which is being called once the animation is done ;)

Oh btw, in your CGRectMake you use for the y-coordinate the x-coordinate again, which probably is the reason why the location isn't accurate ^^

so something like that:

```
- (void)yourFunction {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:indexPath];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(functionEnded:finished:context:)];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:mybutton cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)functionEnded:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:indexPath];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.3];
        [mybutton setFrame:CGRectMake(mybutton.frame.origin.x, mybutton.frame.origin.y, 200, 200)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: I need the button to be flipped and expanded at the same time.
Sample: open iTunes on iPad, and click on a song.